# Netbeans not working after restarting the computer

Tags: netbeans-7, ubuntu-11.10

I have NetBeans 7.1 installed on Ubuntu 11.10. I had to restart the computer to free up some disk space that had been gobbled up by apache. (apache2/error.log had taken up well over 90% of the disk space.) Now I get the following.

```
$ sudo netbeans
/bin/bash: : No such file or directory

$ sudo apt-get install netbeans
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package netbeans

$ sudo apt-get remove netbeans
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package netbeans
```

I can get netbeans to run if I enter

```
/usr/local/netbeans-7.2/bin/netbeans
```

However when I try copying /usr/local/netbeans-7.2/bin/netbeans into /bin I get the following

```
$ sudo cp /usr/local/netbeans-7.2/bin/netbeans /bin
$ /bin/netbeans
/bin/bash: : No such file or directory
```

/bin/bash does exist.

I noticed that I need to refresh my FireFox pages in order to use the back button. So I was wondering if something was overwritten on the disk when it was full. Perhaps some of the file structure is damaged.

Comment: You run netbeans as root?

Comment: Yes.  I want teh engendered executables to be owned by root.